# How to create an array with X amount of values, based on a string?

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to create an array based on the value of a string (integer), for example:

```
// my string
$dogs = '2';

// my array
$dogs_array = array(
                [0] => 'Dog 1',
                [1] => 'Dog 2'
              );
```

So if the string was 4 there would be 4 items in the array. Is this possible? If so how can this be done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With `for` or `foreach`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$i = 1;
$dogs_count = (int)$dogs;
while ($i <= $dogs_count) {
    $dogs_array[] = 'Dog ' . $i++;
}
print_r($dogs_array);
```

Comment: I think you should use loop index in `$dogs_array[]`.

Comment: @Mohammad Why should an index be used? PHP automatically increments a numeric index for you, so no need to do it in your code

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
// my string
$dogs = '5'; //initialize your variable

$dogsArray = array(); // initialize an empty array

for($i =1; $i <= $dogs; $i++)
{
    array_push($dogsArray, 'Dog '.$i);
}

var_dump($dogsArray);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = (int) $dogs;
$dogs_array = [];
for($i = 0;$count>$i; $i++){
    $dogs_array[$i] = "Dogs ".$i;
}
print_r($dogs_array);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.